# Create a string with textvalue from each selected checkbox

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I'm using custom listview with checkboxes how can i create a string builder everytime i click one checkbox?

This is my code of customlistiview:

```
   class MyListViewAdapterExtras : BaseAdapter<ExtrasPreviewClass>
{
    public List<ExtrasPreviewClass> mitems;
    private Context mContext;
    public MyListViewAdapterExtras(Context context, List<ExtrasPreviewClass> items)
    {
        mitems = items;
        mContext = context;

    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return mitems.Count;
        }
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override ExtrasPreviewClass this[int position]
    {
        get
        {
            return mitems[position];
        }

    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        string dpPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "student.db3");
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);
        db.CreateTable<ExtrasPreviewClass>();
        db.DeleteAll<ExtrasPreviewClass>();



        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.ExtrasPreview, null, false);

        }



        TextView txtExtrasName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtExtrasName);
        txtExtrasName.Text = mitems[position].ExtrasName;
        CheckBox txtExtrasCheckBox = row.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.txtExtrasCheckBox);
        txtExtrasCheckBox.Text = mitems[position].ExtrasCheckBox;
        TextView txtExtrasID = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtExtrasID);
        txtExtrasID.Text = Convert.ToString(mitems[position].id);
        TextView txtExtrasPrice = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtExtrasPrice);
        txtExtrasPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(mitems[position].ExtrasPrice);







        txtExtrasCheckBox.Click += delegate
        {
            if (mitems[position].IsChecked == true)
            {

                Connection.Extras += txtExtrasName.Text + ",";


            }


           //in this point  i want to add a stringbuilder which it will add all my textvalues which checkbox is checked into a string.

            //Connection.Extras=  "my string"

            //I dont know if i must use stringbuilder

        };
        //SetOnCheckedChangeListener must be set before txtCheckBox.Checked = mitems[position].IsChecked
        txtExtrasCheckBox.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckChangeListener(position, ref mitems));
        txtExtrasCheckBox.Checked = mitems[position].IsChecked;
        Console.WriteLine("Set the CheckBox " + position + " to " + mitems[position].IsChecked);

        return row;
    }

    public class CheckChangeListener : Java.Lang.Object, CompoundButton.IOnCheckedChangeListener
    {
        int position;
        List<ExtrasPreviewClass> items;
        public CheckChangeListener(int position, ref List<ExtrasPreviewClass> items)
        {
            this.position = position;
            this.items = items;
        }
        public void OnCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, bool isChecked)
        {
            items[position].IsChecked = isChecked;
            Console.WriteLine("Set the " + position + " IsChecked to " + isChecked);


        }
```

I dont know if i do it with the right way. I want to add name from each selected checkbox [image: See picture HERE]into a class or string.

Answer (score 0):

After a button click or something that means the user is done, you want something like this:

```
String result = "";
for(CheckBox cb : checkboxes) {
                    if (cb.isChecked()){
                        result += cb.getText() + ", ";
                    }
                }
```

And then replace the final comma with a '.'

Comment: Where you use checkboxes is my checkbox?   CheckBox txtExtrasCheckBox = row.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.txtExtrasCheckBox);
        txtExtrasCheckBox.Text = mitems[position].ExtrasCheckBox;

Comment: @Dim If you have a place where you add the checkboxes programatically then you should add them to a list `checkboxes` as they are created.

Comment: The problem is that i take unwanted values. Example double values, triple values when i'm scrolling down-up my listview.Thats my problem. Check my current code look my updated answer